# Getting Error 403 from Server "Forbidden" during uploading File to Sitecore

Tags: powershell-extensions

I know that my question is similar to other questions here, but I think I have a different scenario. I'm trying to upload some css files to sitecore (in my case Sc 9.0.1) by calling this url using 
WebClient()
"/sitecore modules/PowerShell/Services/RemoteScriptCall.ashx?user=sitecore\******&password=*&script=\Themes\ExampleProject\ExampleProject Main Theme/styles&sc_database=master&apiVersion=media&scriptDb=master".
This is my code:

```
public string Upload(string filePath)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(Directory.GetParent(filePath).FullName))
            return $"The file {filePath} could not be found";
        using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            string credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"username:password"));
            webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = string.Format("Basic {0}", credentials);
            webClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36");
            webClient.Headers.Add("Accept", "*/*");
            webClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("*****", "*", "sitecore");
            byte[] responseArray = webClient.UploadFile(_targetUri, "POST", filePath);
            return filePath;
        }
    }
```

As an answer from the server, I got, the error 403 (Forbidden) although I entered the admin credentials of the site. 

Does someone know where the problem is?

Thanks

Comment: You are trying to upload to the Sitecore PowerShell Extensions web service. The following page covers how to use the SPE Remoting Module to upload files. https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/remoting . You may also need to review the security page https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/security.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your answer. I found out where the problem is, some parameters where missing. The target database, api version and scriptdatabase. "&sc_database=master&apiVersion=media&scriptDb=master". So i added these parameters to the url and it works.

Comment: Great. Please answer your own question and accept it when you are allowed to. This may help someone in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out where the problem is, some parameters where missing. The target database, api version and scriptdatabase. "&sc_database=master&apiVersion=media&scriptDb=master". So i added these parameters to the url and it works